# Chef/OpsWorks: instance failing on newly released Windows cookbook version

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, berkshelf

With version `>=3.4.5` of the `windows` cookbook release, our instance builds are failing, since we're still on `Chef 11.10 / Berkshelf 3.2.0`.

I added `cookbook 'windows', '= 3.4.4'`  to our `Berksfile`, but the build is still failing, since it's still loading `windows 4.1.1`, even with the added entry to `Berksfile`.

How do I override OpsWorks to use `windows 3.4.4`?

Here's the full error log:

```
Recipe Compile Error in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/windows/resources/auto_run.rb


NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `property' for #<Class:0x007f72ac6f8b20>


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/windows/resources/auto_run.rb:22:in `class_from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/windows/resources/auto_run.rb:

21:  
22>> property :program_name, String, name_property: true
23:  property :path, String, coerce: proc { |x| x.tr('/', '\\') }
24:  property :args, String
25:  property :root, Symbol,
26:           equal_to: %i(machine user),
27:           default: :machine
28:  
29:  alias_method :program, :path
30:  
31:  action :create do
```

Comment: I tried adding `depends  'windows', '= 3.4.4'` to every `metadata.rb` file, Chef logs on OpsWorks still showing version `4.1.1` was loaded

Answer (score 0):

add below in berksfile, this should work for 11+ versions

cookbook 'windows', '<= 1.44.3'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding this to the Berksfile
cookbook 'windows', '= 2.0.2'

Update cookbooks, setup.  I also added it to the wrong git branch, so lost about 20 minutes figuring that out.